# Colombian with EU blue card travelling to the UK

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, colombian-citizens

I am Colombian and I have an EU blue card issued in Germany which is valid for four years. I would like to visit the UK for a week for tourism but I do not know whether I need a visa or just the blue card is enough?
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

A Blue Card gives you free movement within the Schengen area, the U.K. is not part of this scheme https://www.apply.eu/BlueCard/ so you will need a visa to visit the UK https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y

Comment: However, being a legal resident in Germany will increase the odds that the visa application will be granted.